# How to make irregular Honey Comb

Tags: mesh, modifiers, volumetrics

I tried to make this pattern using metaball particles inside volume.
But couldn't acheive this pattern.
DO you know how can I generate a mesh with this porous structure ?

[image]

Comment: The [tissue](http://www.co-de-it.com/wordpress/code/blender-tissue) addon may be helpful for you.l

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 2):

In a regular triangulation of a regular quad topology, vertices connect six edges, and its [Dual](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DualTessellation.html) is a hexagonal mesh..

So as @Leander has hinted in the commentary ..

- Install the shipped 'Tissue' Add-on
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> or use the modifier to triangulate the mesh
- Use one of the Add-on's 'Dual' operations.

[image]

The regions of the mesh which were quad grids will become hexagonal grids.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

- Start with a 6 vertices circle to create this module.

[image]

- Duplicate it with the *Snap* and *Auto-Merge* options activated.

[image]

- Begin to twist and scale it in *Edit* mode withe the *Proportional Editing* option on.

[image]

- Also sculpt it, the *SculptDraw* brush seems good, with an *Autosmooth* value of 1.

[image]